# Duality in Lattices

Tags: abstract-algebra, lattice-orders

I am studying Lattices using the algebraic definition i.e.
A set with 2 binary operations $\wedge , \vee$ that satisfies:
Commutative of $\wedge$ and $\vee$

Associativity of $\wedge $ and $\vee$

Idempotency for  $\wedge$ and $\vee$

Absorption law for $\wedge $ and $\vee$

And I got a question:

Every proposition true will remains true even if we change $\wedge$  and $\vee$?

For example a Lattice is distributive if $a\wedge (b\vee c) = (a\wedge b) \vee (a \wedge c)$

Or equivalently

$a\vee (b\wedge c) = (a\vee b) \wedge (a \vee c)$

Comment: For every statement $\sigma$ there is a dual statement $\sigma^{\partial}$, but it need not be the case that $\sigma$ implies $\sigma^{\partial}$. For example, the statement $(\exists x)(\forall y)(x\wedge y = x)$ asserts that there is a least element. The dual statement asserts that there is a largest element. Neither of these statements implies the other.

Comment: As @KeithKearnes commented, duality does not imply that a lattice satisfying a particular statement automatically satisfies the dual statement. The fact that a lattice satisfies one of the distributive laws iff it satisfies the other is not just "true by duality"; it's true, but requires a non-obvious proof.

Comment: There was an answer by a new user, @Hugo, that explained how duality works, but it was deleted as allegedly unclear and not answering the question. (I disagree with the allegations.)